# Acer E572 lock screen not seen

Tags: windows-8

I have an Acer aspire E572G laptop and the problem is that the lock screen is not appearing even though the cursor is seen. I tried restarting it a few times but no change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Question is very ambiguous, can you give us more information?

Comment: What do you actually see instead?